# clone html content in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, printing

I'm using Angular to create a list of Information. This List should be cloned for my print view.
the content is identical but the view should look diffrent.

So i created two sections

```
    // Web View
<div id="copy-content">
<ng-container *ngIf="document['_source']['79_ikonographie']">
  ....
</ng-container>
</div>


// Print view
  <div id="section-to-print">
    <div id="printable">
          // same content like in ID element copy-content
          <div [innerHTML]="elementHTML"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to clone and render the copy-content section in the printable section ?

This is what I've tried so far.

```
  this.copy = document.getElementById('copy-content');
  this.elementHtml = this.copy.outerHTML;
  console.log(this.elementHtml);
```

Comment: Maybe a combination of `ng-template` and `*ng-templateOutlet` can help you, I would use those in this situation. (https://alligator.io/angular/reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet/).

Comment: this was the perfect solution. Thank You!